# Output html using a Vue template tag, but without having a nested element

Tags: vue.js

My over-arching question is: In Vue, how to output inner html while iterating over a collection but without having to wrap it in an additional div or span.

Specifically: I'm iterating over an array of js objects from within a Vue template. Each object has a "render" method which outputs html.

This works:

```
template:
`<div id="container">
    <template v-for="element in elements">
        <span v-html="element.render()"></span>
    </template>
</div>
`,
```

But I would like to do something like below, because I don't want the output to be wrapped in a div or span. This code produces no error but also produces no output:

```
template:
    `<div id="container">
        <template v-for="element in elements" v-html="element.render()">
        </template>
    </div>
    `,
```

In a perfect world, I would do something like this, but mustache format can't output html:

```
<div id="container">
    <template v-for="(element, index) in elements">
        {{ element.render() }}
    </template>
</div>
```

The desired output:

```
<div id="container">
    (output of element.render())
    (output of element.render())
    (output of element.render())
    etc.
</div>
```

Thank you for any guidance,

L

Comment: have your checked the output for first example which you mentioned works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `<template>` tag completely and use render function in `<script>` tag. Something like this, but this code is not tested, demonstrational only.

```
export default {
  ...
  render (h) {
    return h('div', this.elements.map(function (elm) {
      return h(elm.render())
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vladislav. This puts me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help :)